# Download JellyBean Source Code without any History

Tags: android, android-source, samsung-mobile

Currently i tried following instruction given in [**This Link.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442214/android-source-code-download) Because of huge downloading requirement can not prefer that.

But What i want is only **`Jelly Bean(Nexus 7)`** source **`code`** without any history(no branches,no commits too). like how samsung provides [**Here.**](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=list&menu_item=mobile&classification1=mobile_phone&classification2=&classification3)

Is there anything like this?

Comment: I believe that you get the source code with the SDK since api version 14. It should be in the folder: android-sdk\sources\android-16\

Comment: This is not the full source code, just the Java code of public framework libraries.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Yes your right, my bad.